# Check multiple conditions elegantly

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have a list ranges, and another list of numbers.
I have to output the number if it is out of all those ranges.

```
ranges=['35-796', '811-953', '25-224']
numbers=[12, 30, 345, 800]

#I am looking for an efficient way of doing this
for number in numbers:
    if number not in range(35,797) and number not in range(811,954) and \
       number not in range(25,225):
        return number
```

In the list above, output should be 12 and 800.

I can convert these ranges to any form with some processing, like range object or I can get min and max to put in a condition like `min<number<max`.

I have ~42 of these ranges and ~5000 numbers to check. I am looking for a 'pythonic' and most efficient way to do this.

Comment: The way you're using `return`, you'll only get one number back from the function...

Comment: Why does it need to be efficient? This should only take a split second.

Comment: What's most efficient depends on your data. Need more information about it. Ideally with some code generating realistic data.

Answer (score 5):

Change `ranges` to a list of ranges, then use `any()`.

```
ranges=[range(35, 797), range(811, 954), range(25, 225)]

for number in numbers:
    if not any(number in r for r in ranges):
        return number
```